# make os.listdir() list complete paths

Tags: python, os.path, listdir

Consider the following piece of code:

```
files = sorted(os.listdir('dumps'), key=os.path.getctime)
```

The objective is to sort the listed files based on the creation time. However since the the os.listdir gives only the filename and not the absolute path the key ie, the os.path.getctime throws an exception saying

`OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'very_important_file.txt'`

Is there a workaround to this situation or do I need to write my own sort function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
files = sorted(os.listdir('dumps'), key=lambda fn:os.path.getctime(os.path.join('dumps', fn)))
```

Answer (score 30):

You can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/glob.html).

```
import os
from glob import glob
glob_pattern = os.path.join('dumps', '*')
files = sorted(glob(glob_pattern), key=os.path.getctime)
```

Answer (score 5):

```py
files = sorted([os.path.join('dumps', file) for file in os.listdir('dumps')], key=os.path.getctime)
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting a list of absolute paths for all files in a directory using `pathlib` in python3.9 on Windows

```py
from pathlib import Path

# directory name is 'dumps'

[str(child.resolve()) for child in Path.iterdir(Path('dumps'))]
```

`Path.iterdir()` takes in a `pathlib` object, and so we do `Path(dir)` to get that object. It then spits out each file as the `child`, but as a relative path. `child.resolve()` gives the absolute path, but again as a `pathlib` object, so we do `str()` on it to return a list of strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `os.path.join` with `os.path.abspath`, combined with `map` and `lambda` in Python.

```py
>>>list(map(lambda x: os.path.join(os.path.abspath('mydir'), x),os.listdir('mydir')))
```

This will join the absolute path of `mydir` with `os.listdir('mydir')`.
The output:

```
['/home/ahmad/Desktop/RedBuffer/Testdata/testing.avi',
'/home/ahmad/Desktop/RedBuffer/Testdata/testing2.avi', 
'/home/ahmad/Desktop/RedBuffer/Testdata/text_changing.avi', 
'/home/ahmad/Desktop/RedBuffer/Testdata/text_static.avi', 
'/home/ahmad/Desktop/RedBuffer/Testdata/test_img.png']
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is another solution resulting in an np array instead of list, if it works better for someone.  Still uses os

```
import numpy as np
import os

NPFileListFullURL=np.char.add(Folder_Path, os.listdir(Folder_Path))
```