# Get filenames of a mainpath in order based on first characters of each filename

Tags: python, listdir

I have a `mainPath` to indicate the path to do function `listdir()`. I want to get the name of the files inside the `mainPath`. So I tried this:

```
import os
os.listdir(mainPath)
```

And I get the following result

[image]

However, I would like that the list of paths will be ordered based on the number of each filename. Something like `['01. Enero','02. Febrero', '03. Marzo', ..., '09. Setiembre']`. So, how this could be done?

Comment: Please include the output of `os.listdir(mainPath)` [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), do not link or embed external images. Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Comment: Personally, I'm partial to [natsort](https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort). Like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18415320/15497888) by [SethMMorton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1399279/sethmmorton). `from natsort import natsorted` then just `results = natsorted(os.listdir(mainPath))` (which will handle all sorting by numbers correctly). Although since the names are already zero padded just `results = sorted(os.listdir(mainPath))` should work fine as well.

Comment: One can use this answer for more options on the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657705/make-os-listdir-list-complete-paths

Answer (score 1):

Please try and assign the result from `os.listdir` to a list and sort the list. For example

```py
>>>> res = os.listdir(mainPath)
>>>> res
['06. file', '01. file', '02. file', '10. file', '04. file','08. file', '05. file', '07. file',  '09. file', '03. file']
>>>> res.sort()
['01. file', '02. file', '03. file', '04. file', '05. file', '06. file', '07. file', '08. file', '09. file', '10. file']
```